# How to redirect a domain example.com to www.example in Google Blogger Blog

Tags: .htaccess, dns, blogs, blogger

I want to direct a link which is example.com to www.example.com. I know we can do it using .htaccess. But Im using Google Blogger blog and there we don't have .htaccess.

So please let me know how to do it as both my example.com is opening a different page and www.example.com is opening a different page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blogger - can't use naked domain (ex: yourdomain.com)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152281/blogger-cant-use-naked-domain-ex-yourdomain-com)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will resolve your problem...

[image]